# How to remove a row's bottom margin in Foundation for Emails?

Tags: zurb-foundation

I'm trying out Foundation for Emails, and the first thing that strikes me is that every `<row>` has a default bottom margin of `16px`. **Is there a way to remove this margin, ideally without resorting to SASS?**

I'd like to control the spacing between rows using `<spacer>` only.

Comment: "Is there a way to remove this margin, ideally without resorting to SASS?" Probably not as we generate table elements.

Comment: @DanielRuf I was very surprised that this margin is added by default, as you don't always want a space, and can use a `<spacer>` to control it if you do. I'm even more surprised if there isn't a css class to remove the margin! That being said, I'd accept any solution provided here as an answer!

Comment: So far I only see a padding-bottom at https://github.com/foundation/foundation-emails/blob/develop/scss/grid/_grid.scss#L69. You should be able to overwrite this. Margins do not work in table cells afaik.